# How does "or" in the return function work for this particular code

Tags: python-3.x

I do not know how the "or" works in the return function. I'm not sure when and how it knows to use either of them. ie.match(first[1:],second) or match(first[1:],second)

```
     def match(first,second):

        if len(first) == 0 and len(second) == 0: 

                return True

        if (first[0] == '?') or (first[0] == second[0]): 
            return match(first[1:],second[1:])    
        if (first[0] == '*') :
                return match(first[1:],second) or match(first,second[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an error in this code. Pretty sure it's supposed to be

```
return match(first[1:],second) or match(first,second[1:])
```

That makes more sense. It will return True when one of these statements is true.

Comment: So does it test both the cases :  match(first[1:],second) or match(first,second[1:]) ?

Comment: It'll first try the first one (before the or). If that evaluates to True then it stops there (because the 'or' is already True now). if it is False, then the 'or' is not True yet, so it will evaluate the second part to see if that's True.